# 'use strict'; и this в функции

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код без `use strict` выполняется нормально:

```
(function() {
    var fun = function() {
        this.subFun = function() {
            console.log('subFun');
            return this;
        };
        return this;
    }
    fun().subFun();
})();
```

Но при `use strict` вываливается ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

В принципе, тут все понятно: в strict Mode ключевое слово this должно выполняться только в контексте объекта.

Как переписать код, что выше, так, чтобы он себя вел точно так же при `use strict`?
Вариант через прототип не подойдет...

Comment: не вижу в приведённом коде свойство `show`

Comment: Крайне сомневаюсь, что данный пример кода ведет себя нормально, потому что вызов `fun()` вернет `undefined`, который не может иметь метод `subFun`

Comment: Сейчас я изменил код. Без `use strict` он работает как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    var fun = function() {
        "use strict"
        fun.subFun = function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = 'subFun, all OK';
            return fun;
        };
        return fun;
    }
    fun().subFun();
})();
```